# Puppet Enterprise 2017.1 PAYG Marketplace Connectivity Iissue

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Puppet Enterprise 2017.1 PAYG Marketplace may have connectivity issue to the marketplace when following this document:
https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/ami_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: assign EIP to the instance during launch.